# Regex for repetitive part in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, regex, perl

I have strings as follows

```
car.wheel
car.wheel.mirror
car.wheel.mirror.seats
car.wheel.mirror.seats...
```

I want to just extract `car` from this and avoid the properties of object that are appended such as `.wheel`, `.wheel.mirror`, `.wheel.mirror.seats`, etc.

My current regex is

```
/(.*)?(\.+.*){2}/
```

This works for 2 or 3 as I specify number but I want to create without specifying number of properties, since that can be 0 or more

So I tried below two but doesnt work

```
/(.*)?(\.+.*){0,}/
/(.*)?(\.+.*)*/
```

I am trying this in Jquery/JS if that makes a difference to use something else.

Comment: what about `^([^.]+)\.` ?

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions?  Why not just split on "."?

Comment: @tobias_k yes. I need the starting part.

Comment: @robert Not a bad option.

Comment: It was [jwz](http://www.jwz.org/hacks/) who said "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."  :-)

Comment: @drt: Why have you tagged four different languages?

Comment: @NisseEngström Since it was regex problem and not specific to language. As being python and perl user myself, python and perl also make heavy use of regex, I have included so that those users can also provide their inputs. I have mentioned that I am using Jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

```
var x = $(yourstring).split(".");
console.log(x[0]);
```

Or

```
var text = "your.text.string";
var regex =  /^(.*?)\./;
var matches = text.match(regex);
console.log(matches[0]);
```

Comment: About your second solution: with which method must it be used? Don't forget that this must work with 0 properties. A litteral dot must be escaped.

Comment: even more simpler `"your.text.string".match(/^[^.]*/)[0]`

Answer (score 4):

No need to use regex. A simple split will do and it works even when your string doesn't have any additional properties:

```
'car'.split('.')[0]
'car.wheel.mirror.seats'.split('.')[0]
```

Comment: ++ for not everything is a regexp .. errm wait ..  Does `split()` take a regexp by default and have to be told to take a literal character;  or does it take a literal character and have to be told to take a regexp ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is tagged "perl" for the regexp part of thing. I agree with @silkfire - to deal with this selection of strings you don't really need the full power of regular expressions.

Anyway here is the same thing in perl:

```
my @strings = qw { 
   car
   car.wheel
   car.wheel.mirror
   car.wheel.mirror.seats
   car.wheel.mirror.seats.heater };

say [ split /\./ ]->[0] for @strings
```

(*slightly OT but the tag encouraged me*):

Unlike Javascript strings aren't objects in Perl but you can pretend:

```
perl -E 'say +(split /\./, "car.wheel.mirror.seats.heater")[0]'
```

or even more groovily:

```
perl -Mautobox::Core -e ' "car.wheel.mirror"->split(qr/\./)->[0]->say '
```

With [`autobox::Core`](https://metacpan.org/release/autobox-Core) you chain things and feel all groovy without having to give up perl5.

Comment: Some crazed people even make  shortcut/alias modules for `autobox/Core.pm` so they can do:  `perl -Mabc -e '"a string an object?!both ;-)"->split(qr/\?/)->[1]->say'` ...  ;-)